# Multiple Spark applications instances logging

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

I have Spark Streaming application and I need to run multiple instances on the same EMR cluster. Logging is done using log4j into log file configured. What is the best way to have different logs for each started application copy? Pass different log4j.properties in spark-submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved using log4j MDC functionality and adding sessionID as one of the fields of my log.